# How to spam a button on with a while true without crashing with click()

Tags: javascript

Basically, I tried to do:

```
while (true) {

document.querySelector("#main \> footer \> div.\_2BU3P.tm2tP.copyable-area \> div \> span:nth-child(2) \> div \> div.\_2lMWa \> div.\_3HQNh.\_1Ae7k \> button").click()

}
```

but it just crash, how can I make it stable?

I'm expecting to spam the button but without crashing.

Comment: you could use `setInterval` with some time interval that suits your needs, to avoid freezing the browser UI. But it's not clear why you actually want to repeatedly simulate clicks on a button.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use a while loop, use `setInterval` to repeat your code at a reasonable delay. The following code will run your click code every 500ms, for example:

```
function doClick() {
 // Put your click code here
}

setInterval(doClick, 500);
```

Comment: I did 

function doClick() {
document.querySelector("#question > div.post-layout > div.votecell.post-layout--left > div > button.js-vote-up-btn.flex--item.s-btn.s-btn__unset.c-pointer").click()

}

setInterval(doClick, 500);

and gives me an error

Comment: Well, I can't be of much help if you don't share the error.